# Entity framework "default schema" in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We have a complete application using Entity Framework. There are 30 tables with many interconnected relationships. All of these tables exist in an SQL Server schema associated directly with this application.

(By "schema" I mean a SQL "namespace", not "schema" as in "the definition of my tables").

For example, this schema is created as:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [myApp]
```

Additionally, we have a "master" schema that has data that is common across a few applications. (We use schemas to separate applications within a single database catalog.)

Now, I've been asked to bring up a second instance of our application with its own independent tables. So for example:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [mySecondApp]
```

This new schema is to contain all of the same tables and relationships between them as is in the `[myApp]` schema. It will still be referencing our "master" schema as well.

The problem is it looks like Entity Framework directly references the table by fully qualified name, which includes the schema. (e.g. `MyDB.MyApp.table1` and so on). This means that in order to support this scenario I either need to convince IT to give me another catalog, which will need its own real-time-synchronized copy of the master schema data, or I need to get Entity Framework to reference another schema.

Short of literally find/replacing the schema across the entire EF model, then separately maintaining both models (destroying all the benefits of e.g. migrations), how can I do this? Ideally I'd like a variable in which I can hold the schema, which can be set in the Web.config file, which EF will then pick up on and use everywhere, including in migrations and the application itself.

The pipe dream: Change a value in web.config, run Update-Database, and have a ready-to-go schema with all the tables pre-populated as per our migrations and Seed method. Change the value again in web.config and do it again as many times as desired with different schema names. (Note that the master schema references should remain intact - this is why I'm thinking about some kind of variable.)

Of course also, change the value in web.config on the IIS application server and point the app at the other schema. Then I simply setup multiple deploy profiles with Web.config transforms for each instance on our IIS.

Comment: Very interesting problem.  Are you using an edmx file with EF?

Comment: Sounds like having 2 separate databases (with views pointing to the same master data instance) would require the least amount of elbow grease. Especially if these "schemas" don't need to see each other.